# Proof verification of absolutely convergent series .

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I didn’t quite understand the Absolute Convergence of a series, so  I thought that looking at the proof would help me understand it, but   Unfortunately it didn’t, from my personal understanding to the theorem, i think that it says :

If the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid{a_n}\mid$$
Is convergent then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$$ is also convergent.

So if this is what really says, then i have a proof of it  and not only a regular proof it has an equivalence relation $\iff$.

**Proof:**

$\Leftarrow$

Assume that The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is convergent so $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is also convergent and $$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{-a_n}$$
which means that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid{a_n}\mid$ is convergent.

$\Rightarrow$

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid{a_n}\mid$ is convergent, so by definition :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid{a_n}\mid=\cases{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{-a_n} \\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}}$$
So one of these series is convergent so if the first series is convergent we can just multiply by $-$ and we get that the second onr is also convergent, the same thing if the second one is convergent.

Over all I have two questions:

Is my understanding about the absolute convergent Theorem right?

If so, is my proof valid?

Comment: It is *not* true that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ converges as well!

Comment: I haven't read through everything yet but immediately I can tell something has to be wrong: there are conditionally convergent series which are not absolutely convergent, such as the alternating harmonic series. So the implication is one-directional

Comment: It seems that you are confusing $\sum |a_n|$ with $|\sum a_n|$. – It is *not* correct that $\sum |a_n|$ is either $\sum a_n$ or $\sum (-a_n)$.

Comment: Is the opposite right?@hgmath

Comment: Your understanding of what the theorem says is correct. The converse that you added is false, and the proofs you give of both directions is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you proved is not correct and it seems you don't exactly understand what $\sum_{n \geq 0} \vert a_n \vert$ means. It is just the series of the absolute values of the initial terms. As pointed before, the two are not equivalent (a series which is not absolutely convergent is either outright divergent or it is convergent, in which case it is called a *conditionally convergent series*). [Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) has a pretty nice theorem on conditionally convergent series, I encourage you to check it out. To prove the statement you wrote, it is enough to show that the tail of $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ is Cauchy. But this is immediate since the tail of $\sum_{n \geq 0} \vert a_n \vert$ is Cauchy and $\vert a_n + a_{n + 1} + \dots + a_m \vert \leq \vert a_n \vert + \vert a_{n + 1} \vert + \dots + \vert a_m \vert.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Well i understand now, but i just want to ask if the series must contain alternately positive and negative values or it does not matters ?

Comment: If a series is conditionally convergent, but not absolutely converging, then necessarily it must contain an infinite number of positive terms and an infinite number of negative terms. For if this were not the case, then suppose for instance the series contains only a finite number of negative terms, so after say $n$ terms all terms are positive and the remaining series converges, so the original series would be absolutely convergent, its sum being just the sum of the series after those $n$ terms and the absolute values of the terms before and this is a contradiction.

Comment: If you are asking whether an absolutely convergent series must contain positive, as well as negative terms, then the answer is no. For example the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent (so also absolutely convergent since all its terms are positive), the sum being equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (this is called the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)).